# Is inserting multiple queries takes same time as that of single query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, t-sql, insert

I have a requirement where I have to insert a lots of rows.For inserting we use like this

```
insert into emp(name,age) values('abc',12);
```

This will insert only one row.For inserting multiple rows we can either write insert query multiple times or write a single query with multiple values.For example

**condtion1**

```
insert into emp(name,age) values('abc1',121);
insert into emp(name,age) values('abc2',122);
insert into emp(name,age) values('abc3',12);
```

**condition2**

```
insert into emp(name,age) values('abc',12),('abc2',122),('abc3',12);
```

My question is are both (condition1 and condition2) above takes time?I guess condtion2 takes less time than condition2. If my guess is true then what is the reason for it?

Comment: If you want to send three letters, would you go to the post office once carrying three letters, or three times carrying one letter?

Comment: @mustaccio obviously I will carry all three at one time.This is not technical.I want to technical answer so that If any of my colleagues ask then I have to show them a proof.

Comment: Consider that individual insert statements will each require a separate synchronous transaction log write, unless the entire batch is wrapped in a transaction.  Also, the row constructor approach is limited to 1000 rows.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server at least (can't speak for the other RDBMS you've mentioned, sorry), a single statement will scale better than multiple, to a point. You can test this yourself using your exact statements and data, of course; nobody here can test that for you with your specifics, and your specifics may tilt things one way or another. "Which is faster, x or y?" questions are generally discouraged here because you can test them in your own environment much faster than any of us could throw guesses and logic at you. Especially when you're trying to get an answer for all of the database platforms you've listed - nobody is an expert in all of those and any such answer would either be very biased (like this one) or far too blanket to be useful.

In general, though, the overhead of preparing individual statements (and possibly sending them separately depending on your code and the behavior of your provider) *should* add up, [much like @mustaccio said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90125/is-inserting-multiple-queries-takes-same-time-as-that-of-single-query#comment161770_90125):

> If you want to send three letters, would you go to the post office once carrying three letters, or three times carrying one letter?

This would especially be true in your scenario if each small statement is broken up across individual packets and even different connections. Again, I have no idea how your provider works or how your code sends these statements - if it's a single batch of a variable number of statements, that can actually be *harder* for SQL Server to optimize than individual single-statement batches, since SQL Server optimizes at the batch level.

Note that the `VALUES()` clause has [an arbitrary limit of 1,000 values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/dd776382.aspx), so you may need to create multiple statements depending on how many values you have. The reason is concern over compile time, as [Paul White explains here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82921/the-number-of-row-value-expressions-in-the-insert-statement-exceeds-the-maximum). *Also note: Oracle has the same restriction.*

According to [Martin Smith's testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values/8640583#8640583), compile time at least is minimal and relatively invariable up to a little over 250 values. See these charts (for details please see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values/8640583#8640583)):

> [image: Compile time 1]
>
> [image: Compile time 2]
>
> [image: Compile time 3]

If you go with a `VALUES()` clause be aware that each variation (meaning number of actual value sets) will generate its own plan, regardless of whether you use properly parameterized statements or just inline constants, and this is true even when the database's parameterization setting is set to simple. So you may want to consider using the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` server setting (lots of info [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/) and [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-adhoc-workloads-and-clearing-the-single-use-plan-cache-bloat/) to prevent single-use variations from filling the plan cache (generally a good idea for most systems anyway, unless you are CPU-bound *and* compilation costs are proven to be excessive).

A better answer to this problem is to use [table-valued parameters (TVPs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), which allow you to send sets of structured data through a single parameter, giving you an efficient way to pass data and a single plan that can be reused regardless of the number of values passed. The catch here is I'm not sure Java understands what those are (in C# you can send, say, a DataTable as a `Structured` parameter).

Answer (score 5):

*For SQL Server*: Neither.

To insert a *lot* of rows you should use bulk insert APIs, and thrive to achieve minimally logged insert.

Bulk inserts can be achieved using [`IRowsetFastLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131708.aspx) (OleDB), using the [Bulk Copy Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130922.aspx) (ODBC) or using [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (.Net). All these APIs have in common that they establish a fast insert pipe with the server, and then they start pushing rows. These are not T-SQL statements, but implementations of the TDS [Bulk Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357606.aspx) message. At a higher abstraction layer you can use [bcp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), [`BULK INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement or an [SSIS OleDB Destination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139821.aspx) with Fast Load option enabled.

A second, optional, improvement is to achieve minimal logging. See [Operations That Can Be Minimally Logged](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (bulk insert *can*, ordinary INSERT *cannot*). Read [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(v=sql.105).aspx) for details.

Finally I urge you to spend some time and read [SQL Server Data Loading Performance Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: Yes, bulk is good for large sets, but [for 543 values](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90125/is-inserting-multiple-queries-takes-same-time-as-that-of-single-query/90129#comment161767_90126) may be overkill.

Comment: Yes, 543 is not exactly *a lots of rows*...

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts, using a prepared statement will probably be a good idea since the statement wont have to recompiled by the DBMS for every new row. Something like:

```
insert into emp(name,age) values(?,?);
```

Sending several insert at once will minimize the network latency, in some languages there is a batch update operation which "mimics" this. If your host language does not support this, a possible strategy is to create say 3 prepared statements:

```
ps1 = "insert into emp(name,age) values(?,?)";
ps2 = "insert into emp(name,age) values(?,?),...,(?,?); -- holds 10 rows
ps3 = "insert into emp(name,age) values(?,?),...,...,,(?,?); -- holds 100 rows
```

As long as there are more than 100 rows to insert, execute ps3. Then execute ps2 as long as there are more than 10 rows left, finally execute ps1 for the remains. For 543 rows to insert you will execute ps3 5 times, ps2 4 times and ps1 3 times. In total you hand over 12 statements for the DBMS to execute

Comment: Thanks for answering.You said using prepared statement so by do you mean [java prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)If yes then preparedstatement is used in JDBC and I am using JPA.Also Please tell me why for 543 statements I will use 12 statements,why can not I used single statement with 543 values

Comment: You will have to create statements for every possible number of rows. By creating a fixed number of statements you can keep your code a lot cleaner, and the likeliness that the compiled statement will be reused by the DBMS is much bigger.

Comment: If you are using java you might want to have a look at `executeBatch()`

Comment: The problem is I am not using jDBC,so I cant use executeBatch().If single statement takes 500ms seconds then for execting 12 statements then it will take 6000ms so why should I break,I will insert all 543 values in a single statement itself